# Binding parameters in switch statement

Tags: php

I need a little helping hand in my script. As the title suggests it's about parameters. I have this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['sendit'])) {
    $theusersname = $_GET['theusersname'];
    $totalmarks   = $_GET['totalmarks'];
    $mathsobt     = $_GET['mathsobt'];
    $physicsobt   = $_GET['physicsobt'];
    $chemistryobt = $_GET['chemistryobt'];
    $computerobt  = $_GET['computerobt'];
    $englishobt   = $_GET['englishobt'];


    $totalobt = $mathsobt + $physicsobt + $chemistryobt + $computerobt + $englishobt;

    $modulo = ($totalobt / $totalmarks) * 100;

    $grade = "";

//for grades

    switch ($modulo, $grade) {
        case 'A-1'://100% ro 80%
            if ($modulo >= 79.5 && $modulo <= 100){
                $grade = "A-1";
            } 
            break;
        case 'A'://79% to 70%
            if ($modulo >= 69.5 && $modulo <= 79.4) {
                $grade = "A";
            }
            break;
        case 'B'://69 to 60
            if ($modulo >= 59.5 && $modulo <= 69.4){
                $grade = "B";
            }
            break;
        case 'C'://59 to 50
            if ($modulo >= 49.5 && $modulo <= 59.4){
                $grade = "C";
            }
            break;
        case 'D'://49 to 40
            if ($modulo >= 39.5 && $modulo <= 49.4){
                $grade = "D";
            }
            break;
        case 'F'://32 to rest
            if ($modulo >= 33 && $modulo <= 39.4){
                $grade = "F";
            }
        default:
            if ($modulo >= 0 && $modulo <= 32.9){
                $grade = "N/A";
            }
            break;
    }

//for remarks

     switch ($grade) {
        case '':

            break;

        default:

            break;
     }  



    $query = "INSERT INTO `report`(`name`, `grade`, `total`, `mathsobt`, `physicsobt`, `chemistryobt`, `computerobt`, `englishobt`, `totalobt`, `modulo`, `remarks`) VALUES ('$theusersname', '$grade', '$totalmarks', '$mathsobt', '$physicsobt', '$chemistryobt', '$computerobt', '$englishobt', '$totalobt', '$modulo', '$remarks')";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqliConn, $query);
    //  if (mysqli_query($mysqliConn, $query)) {
    //        echo "New record created successfully";
    //  } else {
    //  echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqliConn);
     $mysqliConn->close();
// }
```

The grading switch statement doesn't work. Because I just can't get what parameter I need to give. Same goes for the remarks too. The code may be terrible and don't have sanitization (which in this case I don't need). I'm also a little bit confuse with the strings I passed for cases. I mean does it have an effect on overall?

Thank you.

PS: If there is already a similar answer out there, which i unfortunately i didn't find, i'm ready to view the link. Please post a little explanatory comment.

Comment: `$modulo && $grade` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. How is that supposed to match any of the cases?

Comment: `$modulo && $grade` is a boolean expression. Its value is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (and not `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'`). However, [`'A' == TRUE` and `'' == FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: It seems like you have no idea how `switch` works. It looks like you should just be using `if/elseif`, not `switch/case`.

Comment: Google "php switch tutorial" and learn how it works. You don't need it here.

Comment: i'm sorry i pasted the code which wasn't meant to. I was checking different solution. It was actually  `($modulo, $grade)`. This can be wrong but it was the actual

Comment: What do you think `($modulo, $grade)` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
    $theusersname = 'theusersname';
    $totalmarks   = 500;
    $mathsobt     = 87;
    $physicsobt   = 82;
    $chemistryobt = 75;
    $computerobt  = 79;
    $englishobt   = 91;

    $totalobt   = $mathsobt + $physicsobt + $chemistryobt + $computerobt + $englishobt;
    $modulo     = ($totalobt / $totalmarks) * 100;

    switch ($modulo) {
        case $modulo >= 33 && $modulo < 39.5:
            $grade = "F";
            break;
        case $modulo >= 39.5 && $modulo < 49.5:
            $grade = "D";
            break;
        case $modulo >= 49.5 && $modulo < 59.5:
            $grade = "C";
            break;
        case $modulo >= 59.5 && $modulo < 69.5:
            $grade = "B";
            break;
        case $modulo >= 69.5 && $modulo < 79.5:
            $grade = "A";
            break;
        case ($modulo >= 79.5 && $modulo <= 100 ):
            $grade = "A-1";
            break;
        default:
            $grade = "N/A";
            break;
    }

    switch ($grade) {
        case 'A-1':
            $remarks = "You have got A-1 ";
            break;
        case 'A':
            $remarks = "You have got A ";
            break;
        case 'B':
            $remarks = "You have got B ";
            break;
        case 'C':
            $remarks = "You have got C ";
            break;
        case 'D':
            $remarks = "You have got D ";
            break;
        case 'F':
            $remarks = "You have got F ";
            break;
        default:
            $remarks = "You have got nothing";
            break;
    }
    echo $query = "INSERT INTO `report`
                        (`name`, `grade`, `total`, `mathsobt`, `physicsobt`,
                        `chemistryobt`, `computerobt`, `englishobt`, `totalobt`,
                        `modulo`, `remarks`)
                    VALUES ('$theusersname', '$grade', '$totalmarks', '$mathsobt',
                        '$physicsobt', '$chemistryobt', '$computerobt', '$englishobt',
                        '$totalobt', '$modulo', '$remarks')";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
INSERT INTO `report`
   (`name`, `grade`, `total`, `mathsobt`, `physicsobt`,
   `chemistryobt`, `computerobt`, `englishobt`, `totalobt`,
   `modulo`, `remarks`)
VALUES ('theusersname', 'A-1', '500', '87', '82', '75', '79',
 '91', '414', '82.8', 'You have got A-1 ')
```

Comment: I jst don't know why the `switch($grade)` statement is not working. Thanks for you efforts

Comment: How could you be sure that `switch($grade)` statement is not working ?

Comment: There is a problem with the $remarks variable. could you please fix it

Comment: It don't send data to DB. It tried this `$remarks = $remarks`. off course, it'll give error but it sends data too. But if i remove it nothing gets sent

Comment: Also see the query. When remarks has nothing it says undefined var: . But when it avaluates true it doesn't output an error but the query sends nothing

Comment: @jan Please use this.

Comment: I tried this already. You put some great efforts to solve my problem. I'll give it another shot. This time Copy/Pasting your code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

`$modulo && $grade` is a boolean expression. Its value is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (and not `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'`).

But PHP is a loose-type language and it changes the types of its values as needed before using them. Because of this, `'A' == TRUE` and `'' == FALSE` and your code produces only `'A-1'` and `'N/A'` grades.

A `switch` doesn't help here. You should use a sequence of cascaded `if`s:

```
if ($modulo >= 79.5) {
    $grade = "A-1";
} elseif ($modulo >= 69.5) {
    $grade = "A";
} elseif ($modulo >= 59.5) {
    $grade = "B";
} elseif ($modulo >= 49.5) {
    $grade = "C";
} elseif ($modulo >= 39.5) {
    $grade = "D";
} elseif ($modulo >= 33) {
    $grade = "F";
} else {
    $grade = "N/A";
}
```

Read how [PHP compare values of different types](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and read how the [`switch` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) works.

Comment: I just did and then saw exact same answer of yours. Thanks a lot for your time and patience. But what about the remarks. Does it need a switch or an if else. I either have to give it the value of Grades or The Mod.